# Is it possible to use a "while" loop in parallel when using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I know that it seems like the straightforward answer is *NO*. Yet, I wonder if there is not a way to get it to work.

Basically, I would like to randomly draw from a distribution and only keep those who respect a certain condition and fill a pre-determined storage matrix and stop once the matrix is full.

Since these are draw, I suppose I can harness Matlab's parallel capabilities but since the completion of the storage matrix depends on the sequence of draws, I feel there is an issue there.

Alternatively, is there a way to use a time-check for the problem at hand. For instance, I would use a parfor with a limit absurdely large but include a way to check the size of the storage matrix at frequent interval.

In pseudo-code, it would give:

- create size of the storage matrix: `A=zeros(100,1); Naccepted=0;Ntried=0;`
- initiate the for loop: `parfor i=1:100000000000`
- do the loop: `x(i)=randn(1,1)`
- check whether it respects the condition: `if x(i)>0, Naccepted=Naccepted+1; Ntried=Ntried+1; A(j,1)=x(i), else Ntried=Ntried+1`
- Check with a timer every 5 minutes (that I have no clue as to implement it in Matlab) if the size of `A` has reached 100 or not. If so, then stop and take the first 100 accepted draw. If not, continue.

I realize that my question is very messy but I fail to see properly which part could work in parallel or not.

---

Ok, figured it out:

```
matlabpool open 8

tic

clear;
j=1;
Naccepted=0;
A=[];
workers=8;

while size(A,1)<=100
    spmd(workers)
       x=zeros(10,1);
       for i=1:10
        x(i)=randn(1,1);
       end
    end
    for k=1:workers
        Z(:,k)=x(1,k);
    end
    for k=1:workers
        V(1+(k-1)*10:10+(k-1)*10,1)=cell2mat(Z(1,k));
    end
        V=V(V>0);
        A=[A;V];
        Naccepted(j,1)=size(V,1);
        j=j+1;
end

Ntried=j*workers*10;
rejection=1-sum(Naccepted)/Ntried;
A=A(1:100,1);

toc
matlabpool close
```

Comment: You cannot because you create dependency between one iteration and the next one while for a parallel execution you need an 'orderless' loop.

Comment: Thank your for your comments. Oleg, this is exactly what I thought. Mark, the positive condition was just to give an example of a simple case, the one at hand is a bit more complicated. The only solution I could think of is to break the problem into the number of workers in my Matlab session and ask 100/w accepted draws for each worker. Any idea about the timer thing ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `while` loop directly is not possible, however, there is a small trick that can be used.

A `while` loop can be decomposed into a `for` loop in combination with checking the same condition as the `while` loop.

If it is possible to use a `for` loop, it can be possible, given suitable use of the variables inside the loop (broadcast, slice, etc), to use a `parfor` loop.

To give you an example:

```
clear

nb_tests=1e8;

tic
i=1;
captured=zeros(1,nb_tests);
while i<nb_tests
    tester=rand;
    if tester>0.5
        captured(i)=tester;
        i=i+1;
    end
end
toc

tic
captured=zeros(1,nb_tests);
for i=1:nb_tests
    respect=0;
    while respect<1
    tester=rand;
    if tester>0.5
        captured(i)=tester;
        respect=1;
    end
    end
end
toc

parpool
tic
captured=zeros(1,nb_tests);
parfor i=1:nb_tests
    respect=0;
    while respect<1
    tester=rand;
    if tester>0.5
        captured(i)=tester;
        respect=1;
    end
    end
end
toc
```

Be advised that the advantage of parallelization kicks in when you either have a lot of iterations or when the content of the loop is more complex.

Comment: 5 years before, you wrote "_Ok, figured it out:_" with a `while` loop.